# Custom date format “fengyuanchen/datepicker”

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using “fengyuanchen/datepicker” date picker plugin, i need date format in **17 May 2021** but when i am changing date format it gives me undefined. Need help, Thanks in advance.

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    format: 'dd MM yyyy',

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' value="05 May 2021" data-toggle="datepicker" />
```

Comment: try: `format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'` ?

Comment: Hi Shree, thanks for reply i tried this but it gives me in this format 17-05-2021 but i want 17 May 2021 format

Comment: That's `dd MMM yyyy`, not `dd MM yyyy`. It doesn't look like the library supports that format out of the box: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/. You would have to format the date output yourself to the format required - or use a better library which does let you use that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever user select any date then you can customize that in your required format and set that value in your datepicker using `.val()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    pick: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //prvent any default action..
      var pickedDate = e.date; //get date
      var date = e.date.getDate()
      var month = $(this).datepicker('getMonthName')
      var year = e.date.getFullYear()
      var new_date = date + " " + month + " " + year
      //set date 
      // $(this).val(`${date} ${month} ${year}`)
      $(this).val(new_date)

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<input type='text' value="05 May 2021" data-toggle="datepicker" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much swati for help, above solution is working in crome but not working in ie 10 n 11 becoz of template literals, is there any alternative of template literals?

Comment: Try : `var date = e.date.getDate() < 10 ? ("0"+e.date.getDate()) : e.date.getDate()`  still this is not perfect solution .You can search on stack you will find similar question try them .